# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') soap library nodejs

Tags: node.js, lambda, soap

I'm using node library for nodejs and when create a client throw this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

```
import {createClientAsync} from 'soap';

const wsdlOptions = {
    useEmptyTag: true,
    envelopeKey: 'soapenv'
};
const soapClient = await createClientAsync(wsdlUrl, wsdlOptions);
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error message because of TypeScript. I simply had to replace

```
import soap from 'soap';
```

with

```
import { createClientAsync, Client } from 'soap';
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same here, the problem is caused by `axios` as mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5011). I don't know exactly why it's happening with versions < 1.0.0 but anyway I fixed it overriding the `axios` version of the `soap` and `axios-ntlm` packages.

Example in `package.json`:

```
"overrides": {
  "soap": {
    "axios-ntlm": {
      "axios": "^0.27.2"
    },
    "axios": "^0.27.2"
 }
```

}